# js minesweeper board and row pushing

Tags: javascript

Trying my hands on a beginner minesweeper project and have a question on nested loops. I understand the basic when its with numbers. However, adding arrays and objects into a nested loop iteration is a bit tricky for mind and need some clarity (understanding the logic better).

For the below code, does the "`const row = []`" reset back to an empty array after every time the inner loop finishes pushing the "tile" variable into "row"? I am assuming it does since X will go to "1", which it'll reset the loop again?

Declaring boardSize as 2, I got an output of:
board First Iteration: `[[{0,0}, {0,1}]]`
board Second Iteration: `[[{0,0}, {0,1}],[{1,0},{1,1}]]`

```
function createBoard(boardSize, numberOfMines){
    // Start of board
    const board = []

    for(let x=0; x < boardSize; x++){
        //Each row is 'x', top to bottom
        const row = []
        for(let y=0; y < boardSize; y++){
        //Each column is 'y', left to right
            
            const tile = {
                x,
                y
            }

             //boardSize = 2, 1) row = [{0,0}, {0,1}] 2) row = []
            
            row.push(tile);
            
        }              
        //boardSize = 2, 1) board = [[{0,0}, {0,1}]] 2) [[{0,0}, {0,1}], [{1,0},{1,1}]]
        board.push(row)
        console.log(row)
    }

    return board;
}

createBoard(2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct, const row is declared in a Scope, which is terminated after the iteration is finished, each iteration will have it's own row variable. Generally a new scope is created if the code is surrounded by Curly Braces `{}` such as If statements, Functions, and Loops, though there are a few extra cases.

The Lowest Scope will override scopes Above it, and variables Defined within a scope are only accessible to that scope and other scopes within it.

```js
let x = 5
let y = 4
if (true) {
  let x = 3 // re-define x in Inner scope
  y = 2 // outer scope is accessible to child scopes
  let z = 1
  console.log(x) // 3
  console.log(y) // 2
  console.log(z) // 1
}
console.log(x) // 5 - since the other scope defined its own x, this remains unchanged
console.log(y) // 2 - Value was changed in inner scope
console.log(z) // undefined - does not exist in this scope.
```

This is generally bad naming practice though.

Answer (score 0):

@Ethan's answer is good, and lexical scope is what your question is about.

I just wanted to share some one-liner options to construct a 2-D array of any length with coordinated-pairs (that seems to be what your function does).

This one uses [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) as a kind of range function, and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over it:

```
(r => r.map(x => r.map(y => ({ x, y }))))([...Array(2).keys()])

// or, if board is not square:
[...Array(2).keys()].map(x => [...Array(3).keys()].map(y => ({ x, y })))
```

This one uses the function [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#sequence_generator_range) as a sequence generator, and has a smaller memory footprint:

```
(r => Array.from(r, (_, x) => Array.from(r, (_, y) => ({ x, y }))))({ length: 2 })
```

Comment: Thank you for the further insights, Rodrigo. This is really helpful for someone like me transitioning from the finance world to a developer role in the future. Will try to absorb this!!